# how to handle UnhandledPromiseRejection when calling a function in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express

I have the following function which reads an array and the passes it to my server

```
let storedProcedure = async (params, storedProcedureName) => {
const pool = await getOrCreatePool()
let request = await pool.request()
params.forEach((parameter) => {
    parameterDirection = parameter.isOutput ? 'output' : 'input';
    request = request[parameterDirection](parameter.name, parameter.type, parameter.value)
});
try {
    return await request.execute(storedProcedureName)
} catch(err) {
    console.error('StoredProcedure error', err);
    return null;
}
}
```

and i call it like this

```
apiRoutes.put('/update/:leadid', function(req, res) {

var param = validateUpdateLead(req.body, req.params.leadid)   
var promise = sqlUtil.storedProcedure(param,'sp_Leads_UPD')


       promise.then((result) => 
        {
            console.log('LeadID:' + req.params.leadid + ' Updated - ' + result.rowsAffected[0] + ' Rows Effected')
            res.json({ success: true, RowsAffected : result.rowsAffected[0], UpdatedLeadID :req.params.leadid }).status(200)  
        })
        .catch(err)

        {
        res.send('error':err )
        }
 })
```

when i do that my system nodeJs complains that "ReferenceError: err is not defined" so the question is how can i pass the error from my function to the call and catch it ? When i have calls which fail because of one or the or the reason i get 
**(node:1512) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'leadid' of undefined
    at promise.then (C:\nodeRoot\CRM-NodeJS\routes\leads.js:55:52)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:1512) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)**
So i hope this is something simple to fix

Answer (score 0):

> (node:1512) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'leadid' of undefined at promise.then (C:\nodeRoot\CRM-NodeJS\routes\leads.js:55:52) at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7) (node:1512)

So this is happening because you are returning null when there is an error in stored procedure, to properly behave you have to throw an error from the stored procedure like

```
console.error('StoredProcedure error', err);
throw new Error(err);
```

or simply you can just remove try catch from the stored procedure and let the route function handle the error like

```
let storedProcedure = async (params, storedProcedureName) => {
   const pool = await getOrCreatePool()
   let request = await pool.request()
   params.forEach((parameter) => {
      parameterDirection = parameter.isOutput ? 'output' : 'input';
      request = request[parameterDirection(parameter.name, parameter.type, parameter.value)
   });

  return await request.execute(storedProcedureName)
}
```